# Generate PDF in Go with a dynamic image

Tags: html, image, templates, go, wkhtmltopdf

I am new to Go and actually trying to figure out the way to handle images in templates.
My goal is to generate a barcode and insert it into a template I wrote.
The program already use go-wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf but lacks about images.
My main question is : what's nicest way to do this ?
Should I generate an image in a public directory then insert into img src tag/property ?

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you might get away by using [embedding image data directly into your HTML pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Thank you @kostix you mean I've to save my png to f/s then convert it to base64 then output as img tag into my template ?

Comment: Simplified, yes. Be sure to first practice on some static data to verify `wkhtmltopdf` will grok it (get some picture, encode it as base64, put to your template and see if you'll get a PDF with an embedded picture as a result).

Comment: Ostensibly, other ways to explore—if this thing will fail for you—is 1) painting your barcode as a set of lines in an embedded SVG image; 2) painting it the same way on a `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @kostix I'm pretty close. Now i'm stuck into another problem. I generated barcode (128), converted it to base64. When I pass it to my template like so :  it breaks my png once I open the pdf. But if I take the content of base64BarcodeUrl and paste it directly as src to my img tag, it works like a charm.
base64BarcodeUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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"
Is there any issue I'm not aware about "injecting" some data ?